# how to determine an element’s ancestors with jQuery in an iframe (eg. like when we do inspect element to view in firebug it shows the full path)

Tags: jquery, iframe, click

I have two iframes in an html page

```
<table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
  <tr>
    <th><iframe id="i1" width="100%" height="100%" src="/wordpress"></iframe></th>
    <th><iframe id="i2" width="100%" height="100%" src="/wordpress"></iframe></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have given the click event to change the href of second iframe when any link within first iframe is clicked so that both iframe have the same page loaded

```
$('a').click(function(e){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     var path=$(this).parent();
     var ahash={
        'id':id,
        'href':href,
                'path':path
        };
     if (getFrameElement().id=="i1")
       window.parent.document.Aaddevent(e, ahash);
});
```

The href is changed by the following method by accessing the id

```
document.sendevent=function(e, ahash){
   if (ahash.id!=undefined) {
      $('#i2', window.parent.document).contents().find('#'+ahash.id).trigger(e);
   } else {
      $('#i2', window.parent.document).attr('src', ahash.href);
   }
};
```

Now what i want to do is i have added "path" in the click event which shows the path of an elements ancestor when done console.log() but not in all cases as desired. I dont want to change the src by accessing the id as i am doing now because this is working fine to a certain point but after that when i want to access tab the href gets blank and i dont get the expected output (means the page view within second iframe does not change). Instead i want to use the full DOM path like given in the following link

http://davecardwell.co.uk/javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery-getpath/

I am unable to fetch the path and use it instead of accessing the iframe's id to change the src. How can i do that so that i can change the path of the second iframe when clicked any tab or link within first iframe

Comment: I have now added var path=$(this).getPath() in the click event and added the js file in my script from http://davecardwell.co.uk/javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery-getpath/jquery-getpath.js and when i do console.log(path) i am getting the path of the element i click but how to use this result in document.sendevent(e, ahash) instead of accessing the iframe id and change the src to keep the iframe in sync

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having difficulty keeping your iframes in sync - when the URL changes in one, you want it to change the other to match.  You might simplify things by just watching the `onload` event of the iframe and when it fires, change the `location` of the other frame to match:

```
$("#i1").load(function (e) {
    var url = this.contentWindow.location.href;
    var frameLoc = $("#i2")[0].contentWindow.location;
    if (frameLoc.href != url) {
        frameLoc.href = url;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes i am having difficulty in keeping the iframes in sync because when the url is same and any tab is opened the href gets blank. You are right when the url changes in one i want to change the other to match but the main problem in what i am doing now is when url remains the same and i view some tab in one iframe, the same thing does not open in other iframe. Is there any other way to make it more dynamic other then using the id of iframe because i want to use this for several iframes and if there is no id then what to do?

Comment: I tried your method just now but in certain links within the page when i click it is showing this error in mozilla "Permission denied to access property 'href' [Break On This Error] var url = this.contentWindow.location.href;" I have then tried the same in chrome it is giving error domais, protocols and port must match. May be it is because of the onload event because the link clicked within iframe is on different domain. Can we manage elements by using their full DOM path as shown in an example in the link i have given in my question

Comment: The click event is not getting triggered in my question when there is a cross domain.

Comment: Those errors are due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).  If the domains, ports, and protocols don't match between two frames, there can be no JavaScript interaction between those frames.  If cross-domain interaction is a requirement, you'll need to run as an application outside of a web browser or stream all requests through one server that acts as a proxy.